Do you know any traditional non-electric Gold measuring devices?
I have a currency system that uses gold coins. Standard-weight coins bearing marks of state sovereigns exist and they have several features to keep people from shaving-off of them; nonetheless, skimming does happen. Therefore, merchants prefer to measure weight of the coins during transactions.
Now, the problem I am facing is that of how? How do that measure the gold after every transaction? The traditional(on earth) method of using scales seems a bit tedious. For larger transaction, sure, you can take the time to measure it, considering the stakes. But what about retail transactions? Measuring every individual coin that comes your way would heavily slow down the speed of business, and therefore, affect profits. Not to mention the impracticality of it in a bustling city market. It might not even be described as bustling with how slowly things transactions will move along.
So, I was wondering if there were any other weight measuring devices(Non-electric) that would be sensitive enough to measure gold and fast enough to not be a hindrance?
Obviously, there is magic, and I can just throw some magic-based scales out there; but I would still prefer that they be based on some real world examples. If I can have a completely non-magic alternative, even better.

(1) Gold was rarely, almost never, used for day-to-day retail transactions. (For example, the smallest gold coin of the late lamented Latin Monetary Union  was the 3.2 grams 10 franc coin which would be worth some 200 euros today.) (2) Modern-ish coins, say those made after 1600 or so, had features which made it visible if somebody grossly altered them. (3) If you accept gold by weight you should be concerned with its purity, which is much harder to determine quickly than its weight.

I remember when people at the market used non-electric scales. Not to measure currency but the weight of the thing you buy (meat, vegetables, etc). Some used the type of weight you put something on it and gives you a number. Some even used actual scales, where you put stuff on one end and then your weights on the other and balance it to figure out how heavy something is. I don't think I'd describe any of that as "slow". I think you might be underestimating how fast measuring something with scales is. Slower than electronic scale - sure. Not orders of magnitude, though.

@VLAZ I see vendors measuring weights using non-electric scales every time I go to buy vegetables. I know they are pretty fast. But, in those cases error of 5% is normal, expected and accepted. No onw fights over 50g in case of a 2kg watermelon. However, Gold requires sensitive measuring and 2.5% error adds up over 100 transactions. And measuring gold with those weighting scales is slow (I have watched goldsmiths measure gold for jewelry a few times. It is a slow process with a some argument and a lot of focus by both parties.)

@VLAZ Even 0.5% of weight difference over 1000 coins is enough of incentive for a  skimmer to make it a full time job. 0.1% will probably not be worth the effort, so I am looking for a device with an error range near 0.1%.

@AlexP (3)Purity is not an issue. There are measures in place for that. (2) Skimming 1% per coin is profitable enough to make it a full time job. (1) I am aware that there may not have been any such devices historically, due to lack of use of gold as prominent currency, as you mentioned. I know I may not get any answers on this one. I couldn't find any in my research. I was just asking in case somebody had come across any such device during their explorations.

Gold in irregular sized lumps and dust was used in Gold Rush territories (US and Australia) and in North Africa on trade routes according to O'Brian in "The Hundred Days". They could use lever balances that you hung from the hand. If you don't trust the merchant, you don't trust their weight either.

Adjacent to the discussion, one method of measuring the amount of gold and by proxy its purity is to weigh the gold submerged in water. By comparing the weight and amount of water displaced one can derive more exactly its purity.

Do you know how pre-digital mechanical vending and slot machines knew what coins were being used? look it up and do that, you drop the coins in a hopper or slot and they fall through the machine being divided and diverted by weight, shape and size, the legit ones of each type end up in their own bins the bad ones end up in other bins and a display turned by gears as each drops through its last gate clocks the numbers of each type up for you .. it's not hard [shrugs], just a process of elimination with a series of counterweights and different sized holes, some clockwork and gears.

^ that's not going to be something you can carry in your back pocket though, but that shouldn't be a problem for a stationary merchants stall, you'll have to allow space for it on the cart if you're moving between towns occasionally though [ponders] might be a demand for ones you can rent when you arrive ;D

Probably best to weigh larger transactions and count smaller ones. All coins would need to be examined anyway to ensure that none had been shaved and nothing but true gold coins were included in the sack of money.

Not enough for an answer, but enough to help in understanding: in the real world, individual coins were rarely weighed. A merchant would weigh all the silver together and all the gold together, etc. There are small pocket devices that can be used to measure individual coins by weight and size as well, if the minting technology is sufficiently advanced. Another thing that helps is chop marks. These are small countermarks stamped onto a coin that identifies a particular merchant who has accepted the coin in the past. Wouldn't take long for a local economy to recognise such marks!

the big advantage of a scale was being able to see all parts of the measurment, instead of just having to take the shops word for it. also you can make ballance scales FAR more sensitive than 0.1% You can make them accurate to 3 decimal places. Also if you are selling things with coins based on weight you are not selling enough for that time to matter.

In practice there were never all that many types of gold coins in circulation; for example:

The stereotypical gold standard British system (1817 to 1937, with an interruption during WW1) there were three gold coins:

The half sovereign, 3.994 g of 22/24 fine gold;
The sovereign, 7.988 g of 22/24 fine gold;
Two pounds, 15.976 g of 22/24 fine gold.


The Latin Monetary Union used theoretically four but in practice only three gold coins:

10 francs / lire / pesetas / lei etc., 3.2258 g of 900‰ fine gold;
20 francs / lire / pesetas / lei etc., 6.4516 g of 900‰ fine gold;
50 francs / lire / pesetas / lei etc., 16.129 g of 900‰ fine gold;
The theoretical 100 monetary units coin was just about never seen in practice.



Therefore, the merchants who for some reason want to weigh the coins can just use a very simple setup, where they have a jeweler's balance and three or four guaranteed good coins, one of each kind. Put the customer's coin on one plate of the balance, your known good coin on the other, see if the balance stays balanced. Takes about five seconds.
Notes

It is really impractical to make gold coins of less than 3 grams or so. This means that the smallest gold coin has a value which can easily cover a full week's expenses for a middle class person, or for an entire working class family. In reality, silver was very very much often used for day-to-day expenses than gold.

The most usual gold coin system used not more than four coins, one of the minimum practical weight of 2.5 to 4 grams, one double that, and one or two at four, five, six or eight times the minimum weight.

In pre-modern times, coins from different countries, different kings, and even different coinages of the same king varied in fineness enough to make a simple weight comparison meaningless.

Since the 17th century onwards coins had features, such as for example  milled edges and embossed margins, which made it easily visible if their weight had been reduced by clipping, sweating or eroding.



Milled or reeded edges make it plain obvious if the coin has been clipped, sweated or eroded.

British coins in the age of the gold standard could also carry the inscription decus et tutamen (an ornament and a safeguard) inscribed on the edge as a protection against clipping, alone or in addition to the reeding.

Frame challenge
What's wrong with scales? And by that I mean simple balance scales. In your post you mention it being impractical to weigh each individual coin, but you don't actually need to do that. Just have a set of weights that corresponds to 1 gold, 5 gold, 10 gold, etc. the sales clerk just puts the correct weights on one side of the scale, the buyer puts their payment on the other side, once the sides match, the clerk takes the money, the customer takes their goods, and it's all done in less time than it takes us to swipe our credit cards and wait for electronic banking approval. This method also removes the possibility of counting errors in the coins, as it doesn't matter how many coins there are as long as the weight is right.
It's possible that a customer will accuse the shop of the weights not being correct, but that's as simple as providing a demonstration using currency that the shop has already verified to be a correct weight. Or just use verified coins instead of the weights (as long as you have enough other coins).
It's possible that a customer will doubt the balance being fair, but the clerk can just offer to swap weight and currency sides of the balance if needed.
I fail to see the problem with this system. Sure it does require a set of weights, and not everyone will need them, as you have to trade a significant volume of goods to actually be concerned about skimming. But if you are, you can probably spring for a good balance scale and a set of standard weights.

How does taking the shops word that the verified money is good any better than taking their word the regulated weights are correct?

@John You're right it doesn't prevent the possibility that a shop couldn't fraudulently add mass to existing coins (and having false weights) and try to cheat people that way. But the real concern is that nobody cheats the shop, not the other way around. It's more about presenting convincing evidence, not eliminating the possibility of a conspiracy.

Frame challenge. There may not be the great, winged, fire breathing ones of legend (at least not around these parts), but what there is is what we got:
Wyvlets.
Well, course we have, Harve is a fine one, stays awake the whole day (most days). What self respecting trader wouldn't have a row of them behind the counter, been a tradition in these parts since the days gold was first invented.

Copyright unknown, found at graygroupintl.com 6-6-2024. Fair usage.
Scales? Shure they shed, but mostly clears them up themselves. Very meticulous they are with the cleaning and never foul their perches. Have you noticed how sweet they smells? Taken a fancy to eating mint, mint and melons - that and the taste of the shiny stuff, like all of them, can't get enough.
Yes, you bet they're certified. Fully Guild trained and calibrated every 5 years in the spring, just like it states on the certificate there. Never had an issue with any of them since they was handed down from pops. 25 years they've been with me, 60 years they've been loyal and on the job - as long as they get their melons and mint.
How they balance the coins on their tongues and delicately place the good ones neatly in a pile like they were their own eggs. You should see them when they get a ringer or shaver, wild they get, hooting and squealing like they got bit by a snake. No customer comes back in this shop after the shame of leaving to the sound of that soul melting chorus.
Oh, metal scales. What a load of compost. Maybe in foreign parts, but not round here. No self respecting customer would trust those toys, unless they're for decoration, but not to weigh anything! No. Trust in the rainbow team. They're the only way in this land.

This is the only correct answer!

Gold is always worth the time it takes to measure
Depending on your civilization and time period, the average gold coin was typically worth anywhere from about \$600-3500 in today's currency... that is ONE gold coin. If you are measuring gold, then you are not doing a casual market transaction; so, it is worth a few seconds to measure these coins as precisely as possible.  The reason balance scales were so popular is because they created trust between the vendor and the purchaser for these large transactions.  When even a small sliver of gold clipped from the edge of a coin could be worth over \$100, there is no reason to rush the authentication process. There are actually faster ways to weigh your gold than a balance scale, but balance scales make it easy to prove if you are being swindled compared to other scales because they tend to be more precise and you can swap which plates the weights and coins are on to show if the scale is unbalanced.  Infact, it was not uncommon for both the vendor and seller to bring thier own weights to make sure that both people are being fair because at those coin values, no one really wants to rush and risk being cheated.
But balance scales are just one test.  Another common test was water displacement.  An unscrupulous person may try to mix thier gold with other metals so that they weigh a bit more for thier gold content in which case precisely measured water displacement could tell you if the coin's weight and volume are consistent with the density of gold.  Using displacement as a metal purity test was common in addition to weighing for larger transactions. Certain types of coins even got reputations for being more pure than others which could affect thier values on transactions where the coin number is too small to measure accurately with displacement.
How preindustrial markets actually worked
Before the late medieval period, the lowest value coins used by most European and Mediterranean civilizations were silver coins which were typically worth about \$70-150 each.  These coins slowly got clipped over time for smaller transactions, but most purchases were actually made in whole coins.  Even cheaper copper coins were not widely seen as necessary until industrialization began to produce larger numbers of cheaper products creating a demand for smaller transactions.
Before industrialization, there simply was not a big demand for "small" transactions like you see in modern stores because people measured value in days of labor, not in minutes.  Depending on thread counts and fiber types, it would typically take a whole day to make somewhere between 5 and 60 inches of cloth.  A basic metal tool could take anywhere from a couple of days to a over a month of combined labor to refine, forge, whittle, and grind.  Also, there was no fast food or individually priced vegetables; the food you bought at market was typically sold by the amphora or bushel (~28-30 liter units), and when you did buy pre-cooked individual meals, it was EXPENSIVE. So, even when you are talking about "small" transactions happening in a pre-industrial context, you are rarely talking about purchases worth less than an entire person's daily income; so, there was actually very little point in trying to rush a transaction because you never had long lines of many customers waiting to make small purchases like you get today.

Spring scales
Most scales in use twenty years ago, and probably your bathroom scale, are spring-based. Normally a spring-based scale has a range of +/-0.2%, but this can be reduced significantly by using a standard weight and adjusting the scale on a regular basis (once per hour, for instance). The time to measure weight on a spring scale is significantly less than for a balance scale because of the energy lost to heat on every flex.
The primary adjustment would be based on the current temperature, so keeping the scale in a temperature-stable environment (or at least in the shade) would help.

spring scales are used becasue they are more compact not more accurate.
